# Обновление данных в БД Mysql WPF

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, база-данных

Доброго времени суток. Необходимо обновить Таблицу в Mysql, а вернее заменить одно значение в одной строке. Таблица (Clients) храниться в dataset. Обновляю таким образом :

```
    internal static void CashAccountReset(string NewCashAccount, string Client)
    {
        using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(ConnectionString))
        {
            MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter();
            string updateComm = "update custodian.orderholders set `Cash Account` = @NewCash where `Order` = @_client";
            MySqlCommand comm = new MySqlCommand(updateComm,conn);
            comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NewCash", NewCashAccount);
            comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@_client", Client);
            MySqlParameter parameters = comm.Parameters.Add(@"_client",MySqlDbType.VarChar,45,"Order");
            parameters.SourceVersion = DataRowVersion.Original;
            adapter.UpdateCommand = comm;
            try
            {
                conn.Open();
                adapter.Update(dataset.Tables["Clients"]);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, ex.Source);
            }
        }
    }
```

Ошибок не выдает, компилируется и выполняется, только ничего не обновляет. Уже часа 2 не могу найти ошибку, хотя скорее всего пропустил какую то мелочь. Подскажите какую?

Comment: Какой тип полей `Cash Account` и `Order`? А ещё лучше - какой получается текст запроса после всех подстановок? Ну или попробуйте значения подставляемых параметров обрамить кавычками: `string updateComm = "update custodian.orderholders set \`Cash Account\` = '@NewCash' where \`Order\` = '@_client'";`

Comment: VARCHAR(45) оба

Comment: @Akina Кавычки не решают проблему. Может дело в том, что я не вывожу в datagrid таблицу и не обновляю в ней а использую textBox ?

Comment: @Akina В базе нет изменений. Таблица в приложении находится в dataset на самой форме её нет, datagrid отсутствует.

Comment: Я знаю как обновить без использования адаптера через ExecuteNonQuery но хочется разобраться и с адаптером тоже.

Comment: Возможно ошибка в добавлении параметров...в строке запроса еще это имя с пробелом `Cash Account`. Кстати, не знаю наверняка, но в строке запроса вы пишете  `Order` в кавычках, а в `comm.Parameters.Add` без кавычек... тут какая-то мелочь, несущественная. Для примера: [UpdateCommand](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter.updatecommand.aspx)

Comment: @DenisBubnov Нет с параметрами все нормально. если убрать адаптер и добавить `comm.ExecuteNonQuery()` обновление происходит, но я хочу разобраться именно с этим методом.

Comment: После создания `adapter` вызовите метод `adapter.Fill(dataset.Tables["Clients"]);`, оставшийся код без изменений, посмотрите, что-то поменялось? :)